# remote rendering of PHP file

Tags: php, nginx, ssh, port, forwarding

this question might quite possibly not have an answer or be quite stupid. I guess we will find out.

My situation is the following:

- I am wokring with an embedded device. On the embedded device there
  are 10-20 webservices running -- you can actually imagine small
  webservers. Each of them is on its own port. This one might have the IP 152.0.0.1
- A top-level web-interface is wrapped around these webservices. This
  webinterface runs on a standard LEMP setup (debian). Say this has the IP 10.0.0.1

To work on the embedded device one can locally jump from webservice to webservice by calling 152.0.0.1:xxxx, 152.0.0.1:xxxy, 152.0.0.1:xxxz in a (local) webbrowser. This works fine. It seems crazy to have a setup like this but I do not have the possiblity to change things on this end.

What I would like to do is to embed the small webservices in the top-level webinterface, which will have a navigation bar where one can chose which one to look at.

Both systems are not in the same network but connected via a ssh tunnel. However, the ports themselves are dynamic, so I can not simply hard-code them in the top-level web-interface. I should be able by building the navbar using dynamic ports obtained from a database -- this is possible. Since there will be multiple such embedded devices there will be multiple ports to forward with the ssh connection. This is the problematic part.

My question is: is there actually a way to get rid on this port-dilemma situation only on the nginx/php7 level? The embedded device should keep its own ports but I would not want to call them explicitely from the webinterface. Also, each device having a set of ports is quite cumbersome. I could use nginx reverse proxy to map the ports to URLs but I would have to do that on the embedded hardware, which is complicated. I could do it on the debian server as well using nginx but this means I would have to forward a whole bunch of ports from the embedded device to the debian server, which is not nice.

Is there a way I can make the embedded device build a page all on its own, using its internal port-scheme and then display that on the top-level webinterface? I am thinking about a command which allows me to do so, e.g.

buildpage($device, $port) on the embedded device alone and "forward" the entire content of that built webpage to the top-level webinterface. The top-level webinterface would then never have to deal with the port-confusion on the embedded device, it just has to say which port it should use, the embedded device internally pre-renders the page and sends it to the top-level webinterface. The point here being, the aforementioned ssh tunnel would not have to forward a whole bunch of ports anymore but possibly onlyone -- wich is the ultimate goal!

I might be overseeing an easy solution here and the approach probably does not make all that much sense but please consider it. In case there is a better option, I would be very keen to know.

Thank you a lot